# Is Bitcoin core V.0.9 not updated on PPA ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, ppa, bitcoin

[Version 0.9 of Bitcoin-Qt](https://bitcoin.org/en/download) just came out. When will [ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin) be updated? In the meanwhile, any steps showing how to upgrade are welcome!

Equally posted on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23773/is-bitcoin-core-v-0-9-not-updated-on-ppa-ppabitcoin-bitcoin

Comment: You need to ask the owner of the PPA about packages in a PPA.

Comment: @dobey Done and dusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the owner of the ppa.

Comment: The PPA has now been updated on the 23/03/2014

http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23773/is-bitcoin-core-v-0-9-not-updated-on-ppa-ppabitcoin-bitcoin